# Allow create if authenticated, allow update if requested userid corresponds to it

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

How to add a security rules in Firebase Realtime Database with the following conditions.

1. Allow `create` if authenticated, the user is not exist from before.
2. Allow `update` if the user trying to update only their data.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I added the first part but i dont know how to add the `update`

Comment: Have checked documentation for Firebase yet?

Comment: This sounds possible by combining https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#existing_data_vs_new_data. Can you show the rules that you've already written, and the code that doesn't work against them?

Comment: `".write": "auth != null && !data.child('userid').exists()"` I just tried this I dont know what to do for update